# Off-by-One error in C

Tags: c, standards

I am trying to execute example from book example (The CERT C coding standard). Book example is full complete program rather abstract code.
**RULE STR31-C: Guarantee that storage for strings has sufficient space for character data and the null terminator** .

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stddef.h>

enum {ARRAY_SIZE = 32 };
int main(void) 


char dest [ARRAY_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5};
char src[ARRAY_SIZE];
size_t i;   

for (i = 0;src[i] && (i < sizeof(dest)-1);++i)  
{
dest[i] = src[i];

}

dest [i] = '\0'; //this over writing the dest[0],Right?

printf("original -> copied \n");

for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
{
  printf("   %2d        %2d\n", src[i], dest[i]);
}

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
original -> copied 
    0         0
    0         2
    0         3
    0         4
    0         5
```

Question 1. I understand the dest[0] -overwritten the'\0'.It should not happen...how to fix or change  this design.

Question 2 : The src [] all become 0. why? can not understand. or i miss something basic :(

Comment: Regarding the "this over writing the dest[0]" comment, that is wrong. After the loop ends the variable `i` will be equal to `sizeof(dest) - 1`.

Comment: This doesn't look like you copied the book's contents right. It's not demonstrating what it was intended to demonstrate.

Comment: When you declare a local (and non-static) variable, like for example `src`, then if you do not initialize it the variable will remain uninitialized. Such uninitialized variables and data will have an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: **The src [] all become 0. why?** I can't see that you have initialized anything to it either.

Comment: Fixed. Now working as expected. my bad. wrongly input src and dest. ie. they are u inter changed.

Comment: **src[i] && (i < sizeof(dest)-1)** what are you trying to achieve with this in for loop? because src[i] seems to be empty only

Comment: `dest[i] = src[i];` is wrong you have to do this `src[i] = dest[i];` because you have initialised the dest not src

Comment: @eRaisedToX:  as mentioned in book "to prevent buffer overflow ,either limit copies through truncation or ensure that the destination is of sufficient size to hold the char data to be copied and null the termination char ". Non compliant version  for (i = 0;src[i] && (i < sizeof(dest));++i)

Comment: @Chandra, yeah that's okay but what I meant pointing this out was that you weren't assigning anything to src[i] earlier, I think now you have figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The src [] all become 0. why? can not understand. or i miss something
>   basic :(

You haven't initialized anything to `src` either.

> dest [i] = '\0'; //this over writing the dest[0],Right?

My question is Why do you think so ? After all your `i` is not equal to `0`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Now working as expected. my bad. wrongly src[] and dest[] inter changed.